# How to get all possible combination of jagged arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, permutation

I have an argument in function which expect array of arrays like = `[[a,b], [1,2], [*,#]]`. The number of arrays in array may varys. It can be one, two or many.

How to get all possible variations of arrays values, like:

```
a1*
a1#
a2*
a2#
b1*
b1#
...
```

I know how to do it if the number of arrays is known. But how to combine if the number of arrays is not known?

**Update:**

```
let first = [`a`, `b`];
let second = [`1`, `2`];
let third = [`*`, `#`];

for (let i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < second.length; j++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < third.length; k++) {
            console.log(first[i] + '/' + second[j] + '/' + third[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: backtracking is the keyword you are looking for

Comment: @AndrewL64 I added a code sample what I have for now.

Comment: @Nastro Great! I have voted to re-open this question again. Cheers.

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed. Don't see anyting wrong with this question

Comment: @AshishModi That is because it has been updated by the OP. Please click the `reopen` link below the question if you feel that the updated question should be open again.

Comment: @AndrewL64 I don't see that link. Is it because I don't have enough reputations?

Comment: @AshishModi Yes, you need 3k+ rep to reopen closed questions.

Comment: I voted for re-opening : OP added attempts to solve the problem